# setImageResource noticable pause during Translate animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an ImageView that changes it's image resource after completed repeats of translate animation. The problem i have is that there is a noticable delay when the images swap themselves.

Is there any way to avoid this? Make it smooth?

Comment: you should post your code

Comment: I would but I'm at work right now. I'll add it when i comeback home but in general i made a listener for translate animation and i have 2 animations translate animations. On animation end the imageview program sets: [delay about here] setResource < second image> and animation 2 starts.